# What is the difference between Blob created and Blob renamed?

Tags: azure

I want to create a new data connection in Azure. But I don't know if I should choose Blob created or Blob renamed?

What is the difference between Blob created and Blob renamed?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage?tabs=event-grid-event-schema#list-of-the-events-for-azure-data-lake-storage-gen-2-rest-apis):

**Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated**

Triggered when a blob is created or replaced.
Specifically, this event is triggered when clients use the CreateFile and FlushWithClose operations that are available in the Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 REST API.

**Microsoft.Storage.BlobRenamed**

Triggered when a blob is renamed.
Specifically, this event is triggered when clients use the RenameFile operation that is available in the Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 REST API.